# Error in setwd(bundleDir) : cannot change working directory

Tags: r, shiny, openair

Can I develop a R Shiny app that requires other packages? For instance,

ui.R,

```
shinyServer(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Shiny App"),

    sidebarPanel("side bar"),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myPlot")
      )

    )

)
```

server.R,

```
shinyServer(

  function(input, output, session) {

    output$myPlot = renderPlot({

      library("openair")
      scatterPlot(selectByDate(mydata, year = 2003), x = "nox", y = "no2",
                  method = "density", col = "jet")
    })
  }

)
```

Run the app,

```
> runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4459
Loading required package: lazyeval
Loading required package: dplyr

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: maps
(loaded the KernSmooth namespace)
```

I get this result on my local machine,

[image]

But when I try to deploy the app, I this this error below,

```
> setwd("C:/.../myapp")
> library(shiny)
> library(shinyapps)

Attaching package: ‘shinyapps’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    hr

> deployApp()
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading application bundle...
Error in setwd(bundleDir) : cannot change working directory
```

What is going on? Does it mean that I **cannot** integrate/ import the native R with other packages (for instance openair)?

**EDIT:**

```
> require(openair)
> deployApp()

Uploading application bundle...
Error in setwd(bundleDir) : cannot change working directory
```

Comment: If that's a dependency problem, see `?shinyapps::appDependencies`. It may help.

Comment: where is `?shinyapps::appDependencies`?

Comment: @teelou Simply enter `?shinyapps::appDependencies` in R.

Comment: @Pascal. thanks but I still get the same error. please see my edit above.

Comment: Did you try running Rstudio as admin?

Comment: how do you run Rstudio as admin?

Comment: I think the problem is on the `working directory`.

Comment: Set working directory with the path of your app. Then run deploy app command.

Comment: I set that but still get the error. it is driving me crazy!

Comment: `setwd("C:/EasyPHP/data/localweb/tests/r/myapp")`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `setwd()` with absolute path in deployed app, since you are not on your computer anymore but on a different server. You can only use `setwd()` with relative path to your app folder.